# Phonegap 2.6 - notification prompt not working after upgrade for iOS

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

Since upgrading to phonegap 2.6 from 2.4 the method navigator.notification.prompt has stopped working. Xcode spits out this error:

```
 ERROR: Method 'prompt:' not defined in Plugin 'Notification'
-[CDVCommandQueue executePending] [Line 103] FAILED pluginJSON = ["Notification1135621647","Notification","prompt",["Are you sure you want to permanently delete this code?","Delete Tracking Code FFHFDCVHHGG",["Delete","Cancel"]]]
```

This is how I set up the call to prompt, its pretty much straight out of the PhoneGap documentation.  The event is triggered from a click event via backbone.

```
navigator.notification.prompt(
    'Are you sure you want to permanently delete this code?',  // message
     onPrompt,                                                 // callback to invoke with index of button pressed
    'Delete Tracking Code ' + self2.options.parentModel.toJSON().track_code.toUpperCase(),            // title
    ['Delete','Cancel']          // buttonLabels
);

function onPrompt(button) {
    if (button === 1) {
        self2.options.parentModel.clear();  // Remove the item from local storage
    nzp.router.navigate('tracking', {trigger: true}); // Navigate to the tracking page
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The confrim method does not work either, however alert does.

I have noticed that when I view the site in a browser I am getting a new error message too which says cordova_plugins.json 404 (Not Found).  I am not sure what this is for or if its related to my issue.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the notification was working fine.  The issue was related to my path to CordovaLib.xcodeproj not getting updated when I updated the project so it was pointing to an older version